Following up (2024) does aws codepipelines support multiple repositories?
I'm trying to build an MVP and want to use aws code pipelines.
But for an MVP a pipeline per repo is too much last stack overflow i saw was in 2022, was wondering  if this is still valid?
AWS Doc is quite large and I'm getting lost, i found this:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/action-reference-CodestarConnectionSource.html

Basically i would like to have at least 2 repositories, 1 for the pipeline and 1 for the logic, more if possible.
Thanks in advance :)
I review the current aws doc Link but i don't see clearly if codepipelines support multiple sources, if not i'm guessing i will need to do a chain of pipelines to achieve an MVP.

Use two sources in an AWS-CodePipeline pipeline
This has been already asked here and short question to your answer is yes you can.

thanks for the pointer, just clarifying the trigger still can be only 1 github project (repository/source) correct?
AWS codepipeline does not support multiple source triggering correct?
